# Lag for just part of AJAX response

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I made a simple chat. It's working properly, but not behaving as expected. When a user submits a message, the user's name, time and message are supposed to display.

It so happens that the username and response appear first **and the time seems to be inserting itself after a slight delay** (that's the lag). I can't figure out why, especially since the response is (or at least seems to be) sent as a whole and nothing is being inserting once the response is sent from the server...

Here's the link to the [chat](https://mysql-raigovind93.c9users.io/Archive/Chat%20App%20(Real)/chat.php). You can input dummy username and dummy messages.

And here are the important pieces of code:

**PHP**

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $time = date('g:ia', $row['time']);
        echo "<p class=\"message\"><i>{$row['username']}</i> ($time): {$row['content']}</p>";
    }
```

**JavaScript**

```
ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (ajax.status === 200 && ajax.readyState === 4) {
        document.getElementById('messagesArea').innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
    }
};
```

Comment: it looks like the time isn't always present in the first response after you post a message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your culprit is this section of [the script](https://mysql-raigovind93.c9users.io/Archive/Chat%20App%20(Real)/js.js):

```
var content = document.getElementById('messageBox').value;

if ( content === '') {
    return;
} else {
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var username = document.getElementById('signedin').innerHTML;

    document.getElementById('messageBox').value = '';

    ajax.open('POST', 'postmessage.php', true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (ajax.status === 200 && ajax.readyState === 4) {

            // if there are errors echoed from the PHP file
            if (ajax.responseText != "") {
                document.getElementById('mysqliError').innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                return;
            }

            document.getElementById('messagesArea').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p class="message"><i>' + username + '</i>: ' + content + '</p>');
        }
    };
    ajax.send('username=' + username + '&content=' + content);
}
```

Notice this line: `document.getElementById('messagesArea').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p class="message"><i>' + username + '</i>: ' + content + '</p>');`

You are inserting the message, *without* the time, into `#messagesArea`. Then, in `getRecentMessages` later, it is set to fetch the entire chat log from `displaymessages.php` and overwrite `#messagesArea` with the content of the output, which *does* have the time.

Comment: holy smokes... you're absolutely right... how did you read through the code so fast...

Comment: @GovindRai Years of experience ;) Next time, try tracing your steps by running each line of your code in your head first; this will allow you to catch any logic errors.

Comment: You're right on that as well... I will surely do that and more before my next post. Thank you!